# How to send notification to user when his data on firebase changes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How to send notification to the user in a flutter application even when the app is closed when a field in firebase database change

Comment: Have you looked at this [https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_function] and this [https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) and [Firebase Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) for this.

1. A Cloud Function is triggered (`onWrite)`, when the user document changed
2. The Cloud Function sends a Firebase Messaging Notification to this user.

Note: For sending the Firebase Messaging Notification you need to store the Firebase Messaging Token of the user in a database, so you can say that you want to send a notification to specific user.